# Need count of row groups without temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a proprietary SQL system that does not allow the use of temp tables.  I'm trying to get a count of how many claims a member has with the detail included:

```
    declare @t table(claim int, name varchar(50))

    insert into @t values(1, 'Anderson'),
                         (1, 'Anderson'),
                         (2, 'Anderson'),
                         (2, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson'),
                         (3, 'Anderson');
```

The result I want is:

```
    Name   Claim   Count
   Anderson  1      2
   Anderson  1      2
   Anderson  2      2
   Anderson  2      2
   Anderson  3      6
   Anderson  3      6
   Anderson  3      6
   Anderson  3      6
   Anderson  3      6
   Anderson  3      6
```

I can solve this in SQL Server using temp tables:

```
    select claim, name, count(name) as count
    into #counts
    from @t
    group by claim, name;

    select * 
    into #detail
    from @t;

    select b.claim, b.name, a.count
    from #counts a
    inner join #detail b
    on a.claim = b.claim
    and a.name = b.name;
```

However, as I mentioned earlier this has to be run out of a proprietary SQL system that does not allow the use of temp tables.  I've tried using a CTE but I can't get it to give me the detail:

```
    ;with cte
    as(
    select claim, name, row_number()over(partition by claim, name order by claim) as rn
    from @t
    )
    select name, claim, max(rn) as counts
    from cte
    group by name, claim;
```

How can this be solved without a temp table?

Comment: [edit] your question to add a tag for the DBMS engine you're using (SQL Server?).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know which DBMS it is.  Like I mentioned, it's a proprietary version of SQL that the company created themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the window function for `count(*)`:

```
select claim, name, count(*) over (partition by claim, name)
from @t t;
```

Comment: @jackstraw22 Can you mark the response as the answer then? That's how SO works - questions get **answered** and marked as such so that others can find answers.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that?